# $\lim\inf a_n = 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that for every $m$ in the natural numbers there is $n$ in the natural numbers such that $a_n = \frac{1}{m}$.
Prove $\lim\inf a_n = 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

I want to some suggestions on how to "approach" this problem because as it is all that i am seeing is that infact there is no n for the expresion a_n i double checked with other peers and there is no miscopy this leaves me kind of distraught.

i need to understand how to approach this in general if there is any advice for this i would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What if $a_{2n}=\frac1n$ and $a_{2n+1}=-1$? This matches the condition of the problem statement, but we have $\liminf a_n=-1$.

Comment: But the sequence is assumed to be positive.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Prove that there is a subsequence converging to $0$.

Comment: So if there is a subsequence that converges to 0 does this mean that the sequence will also converge to 0 if and only if the sequence is convergent? azarel

Answer (score 0):

For any $\epsilon > 0 $ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ for how many $n>N$ can you find $0 < a_n < \epsilon$?